# Find the value of a key using another key of the same node of JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to find the state of a component in this JSON.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "name1",
        "childFolders": [
            {
                "id": 60,
                "name": "name2",
                "childFolders": [
                    {
                        "id": 72,
                        "name": "Simulator",
                        "childFolders": [
                            {
                                "id": 235,
                                "name": "generic data pumper",
                                "childFolders": [],
                                "childComponents": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 14,
                                        "name": "TCP Client",
                                        "state": "ERROR",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 46256
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 99,
                                        "name": "A4_Timer",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 102,
                                        "name": "A2_Timer",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 108,
                                        "name": "A8_Timer",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 113,
                                        "name": "Timer MRO",
                                        "state": "RUNNING",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 119,
                                        "name": "A1_Timer",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 121,
                                        "name": "A3_Timer",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 124,
                                        "name": "TImer URO",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 236,
                                        "name": "Demographics Reporter Generic",
                                        "state": "RUNNING",
                                        "type": "ROUTE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 299,
                                        "name": "TImer for UIS",
                                        "state": "STOPPED",
                                        "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                        "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                        "outboundQueueSize": 0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "childComponents": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 920,
                        "name": "Get_JavaScript_Counter_Value",
                        "childFolders": [],
                        "childComponents": [
                            {
                                "id": 916,
                                "name": "HTTP Server",
                                "state": "RUNNING",
                                "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT",
                                "inboundQueueSize": 0,
                                "outboundQueueSize": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 917,
                                "name": "Get_JavaScript_Counter_Value",
                                "state": "RUNNING",
                                "type": "ROUTE"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "childComponents": []
            }
        ],
        "childComponents": []
    },
    "error": null
}
```

I generated classes for the JSON from *json2sharp.com*.

```
public class ChildFolder2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<object> childFolders { get; set; }
    public List<object> childComponents { get; set; }
}

public class ChildFolder
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildFolder2> childFolders { get; set; }
    public List<object> childComponents { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildFolder> childFolders { get; set; }
    public List<object> childComponents { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON is stored as a string. I am using JSON.NET. But any solution without using JSON.NET will be helpful too.
So now if I have a **name** of the component, I have to find the **state** of that component. The type of component will be **"COMMUNICATION_POINT"**.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your classes should look like this:

```
public class Component
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int inboundQueueSize { get; set; }
    public int outboundQueueSize { get; set; }
}

public class Folder
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<Folder> childFolders { get; set; }
    public IList<Component> childComponents { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<Folder> childFolders { get; set; }
    public IList<Component> childComponents { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can find all components by recursion:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        Root r = parse(content); //view JSON.NET or something else
        List<Component> components = r.data.childComponents.where(c=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.name) && c.type == "COMMUNICATION_POINT").toList();
        components.AddRange(r.data.childFolders.Select(ExtractComponentsFromFolers));
    }

      public static List<Component> ExtractComponentsFromFolers(Folder folser)
      {
        if (folser == null) return new List<Component>();
        List<Component> result = folser.childComponents.where(c=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.name) && c.type == "COMMUNICATION_POINT").toList();
        result.AddRange(folser.childFolders.Select(ExtractComponentsFromFolers));
        return result;
      }

}
```

Most probably you have to add more Null check condition but I think it's what you looking for.

Comment: You don't need separate `Data` and `Folder` classes, as they are identical; you can use `Folder` in the root:  `public Folder data { get; set; }`

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Ilya.Sulimanov. I think the parameter is missing for ExtractComponentsFromFolders() since it takes a folder as parameter. How should I give the particular folder as parameter??